# Where am I going wrong in this simple algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, ring-theory

First some background on the problem, I'm trying to show that for a (not necessarily commutative) ring $R$ with unity, if $a,b\in R$, where $a$ has an inverse, and $b$ is nilpotent, then $a+b$ has an inverse.  Now I'm not ready for any spoilers yet, but I was fooling around and said okay suppose $(a+b)^{-1}$ exists, then $1=(a+b)^{-1}(a+b)=(a+b)^{-1}a+(a+b)^{-1}b$.  Since $b$ is nilpotent, let $n$ be the minimum such value that $b^n=0$.
Now $1b^{n-1}=(a+b)^{-1}ab^{n-1}+(a+b)^{-1}bb^{n-1}=(a+b)^{-1}ab^{n-1}$
So we have that $b^{n-1}=(a+b)^{-1}ab^{n-1}$
but then it must be that $1=(a+b)^{-1}a$, but this can't possibly hold in general, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your last step, you cancel $b^{n-1}$ from both sides, but you cannot do this because you are not in an integral domain.

Compare:

$$ab^n=b^n$$

for all $a$; therefore

$$a=1$$

for all $a$.